# Assign variables to child template in {% include %} tag Django

Tags: html, django, variables, include, django-templates

I have this code(which doesn't give me expected result)

```
#subject_content.html
{% block main-menu %}
    {% include "subject_base.html" %}
{% endblock %}


#subject_base.html
....
....
    <div id="homework" class="tab-section">
        <h2>Homework</h2>
            {% include "subject_file_upload.html" %}
    </div>
```

child template:

```
#subject_file_upload.html
    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

and my view

```
#views.py
@login_required
def subject(request,username, subject):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CarsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    form = CarsForm()
    return render_to_response('subject_content.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The above code creates HTML in the way I want it to be, however the form does not update database.

BUT,

If I skip the middle template and go directly to the uploading form, it works fine:

```
#subject_content.html
{% block main-menu %}
    {% include "subject_file_upload.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

Help me please to make it work with middle template. 
I want to do this, because I don't wan't to type the same code more than once.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `include` with `with`?

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Like @Besnik suggested, it's pretty simple:

```
{% include "subject_file_upload.html" with form=form foo=bar %}
```

The [documentation for `include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#include) mentions this. It also mentions that you can use `only` to render the template with the given variables only, without inheriting any other variables.

Thank you @Besnik

Comment: For completeness note that if you want to render the template only with the given variables (and doesn't inherit the parent context) you can add the "only" option:  {% include "path/to/template.html" with form=form only }}

Comment: For completeness again, here is the link to "with": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: @Vor If my view returns `context["these_items"]` and `context["other_items"]`, can I use include with this to substitute `{% for item in these_items %}` with `{% for item in other_items %}` ?

Comment: for some reason, if the variable has an _ in its name, it doesn't work. Example: {% include "subject_file_upload.html" with my_form=form foo=bar %} . Any explanation for this?