# Django {% include %} tag displays hardcorded string but not variable

Tags: django, django-inheritance

I want one template to inherit a variable from another template using the Django `{% include %}` tag. But it's not happening.

`section.html`, the template to inherit from:

```
{% block section1 %}
<p>My cows are home.</p>
--> {{ word_in_template }} <--
{% endblock %}
```

`index.html`, which should inherit `word_in_template` from `section.html`:

```
{% include "section.html" with word_in_template=word_in_template %}
```

I've also tried `{% include "section.html" with word_in_template=word %}`.

My view:

```
def myblog(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def section(request):
    word = "frisky things."
    return render_to_response('section.html', {'word_in_template':word})
```

Output for `section.html` in Chrome:

```
My cows are home.

--> frisky things. <--
```

Output for `index.html` in Chrome:

```
My cows are home.

--> <--
```

I'm following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639306/assign-variables-to-child-template-in-include-tag-django) but it doesn't work for me. `"frisky things"` shows if I load `section.html` but it doesn't show on `index.html`. However, the hardcoded string `My cows are home` shows up on `index.html`.

I think I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) right too. But I'm new so maybe I'm not reading things right or something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `render_to_response` is obsolete, you should be using `render` instead.

Comment: Blocks are useful when you use template inheritance to *extend* another template, e.g. `{% extends 'base.html' %}`. When you use `{% include %}` you aren't using template inheritance, so it doesn't make sense to include `{% block section1 %}` in your `section.html` template.

Comment: Thanks for these too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include `section.html` in your `index.html` template, it doesn't automatically include the context from the `section` view. You need to include the context in the `myblog` view.

```
def myblog(request):
    word = "my_word"
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'word_in_template':word}))
```

In the template, the correct way to do the include is `word_in_template=word_in_template`, since `word_in_template` is the key in the context dictionary.

```
{% include "section.html" with word_in_template=word_in_template %}
```

Comment: This gives me a NameError, `name 'word' is not defined`. So, I have to add the variable `word = "frisky things."` to the `myblog` view too?

Comment: Yes, if you include `word` in your context, you have to define it in the view.

Comment: Ok. Just clarifying because I thought `{% include %}` would make the code more DRY. Thanks!

Comment: The `{% include %}` tag makes your templates more DRY, it doesn't automatically pull in template context from other views.